# Contextual jQuery selector does not find some elements, why?

Tags: jquery

If I understand the `context` parameter correctly as described in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), `p` in the following is a collection of two items as expected:

```
const text = "<body><div class='a'> <p>Test</p> <p>Test 2</p> </div></body>";
const p = $("p", text);
```

But why do the following all return no results?

```
const d = $("div", text);
const b = $("body", text);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OlGe/d7efcpv0/29/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the outerHTML of the jQuery object which gets created from `text`, you'll see that the `body` element is removed. This is because you cannot append a `body` element using jQuery. One should already be present in the DOM, and you cannot append another.

Therefore there is no `body` element to find within the `text` jQuery object. Here's an demo of that:

```js
const text = $("<body><div class='a'> <p>Test</p> <p>Test 2</p> </div></body>");
console.log(text[0].outerHTML) // no body!
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see in the above output, the `div` then becomes the root element of the jQuery object.

From there you're effectively then performing `$('div').find('div')` - ie. trying to look for the element within the element that contains it. As such nothing is returned.